# How can i fix the bottom navigator error in dart

Tags: java, flutter, dart, error-handling, helper

I was making a BottonNavigation bar in flutter dart and i am getting an error

the code is
This the code

[image]

the error is
And this the error pls help

[image]

I want a solution for this error if someone can help me i will thank them a lot

[The console version is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvn0M.png)

Comment: can you add the full error

Comment: this all the error i was going to create an app with a home and account setting and i can't because i am can't and i am a beginner pls help

Comment: attach the error from you are getting in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass NavigationDestination instead of NavigationDrawerDestination in the destinations params

** sample code snippet **

```
bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.commute),
            label: 'Commute',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
            label: 'Saved',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

follow official documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html (material you/3)

or If you are using other package for it check its documentation

or you can also use
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html (material 2)